# How to allow external process to connect pod of k8s?

Tags: kubernetes

Here's my environment, I have k8s cluster and some physical machines outside k8s cluster. Now I create a pod in k8s, and this pod will act like a master to create some processes in these physical machines outside k8s cluster. And I need to establish rpc connection between the k8s pod and these external processes. I don't want to use k8s service here. So what kind of other approach I can use to connect a pod in k8s from external world.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to set up your CNI networking in such a way that pod IPs are routable from outside the cluster. How you do this depends on you CNI plugin and your existing network design. You could also use a VPN into the cluster network in some cases.

Comment: Could you provide me more infos about how to set up CNI networking ? Some tutorial articles would be helpful, thanks

Comment: CNI is a standard, not a specific thing. Which plugin you are using depends on what you chose when you set up and installed Kubernetes. Calico and Flannel are both common choices, for example. And even within those, you would need to read up on their underlying routing engines a bunch.